# #1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' não é válida para CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'

Tags: mysql

Por que havendo um INNER JOIN a QUERY retorna o erro **#1253**, mas sem o INNER JOIN a QUERY retorna os registros corretamente, ambas são ?

A query é simples, desse modo funciona:

```
SELECT 
    a.* 
FROM 
    `produtos` a
WHERE 
    a.`titulo` LIKE '%".$termo_pesquisa."%' collate utf8_general_ci 
OR 
    a.`descricao` LIKE '%".$termo_pesquisa."%' collate utf8_general_ci
```

A incrementação retorna o erro:

```
SELECT 
    a.* 
FROM 
    `produtos` a
INNER JOIN
    `categorias` c
ON 
    c.`cat_id` = a.`categoria`
WHERE 
    a.`titulo` LIKE '%".$termo_pesquisa."%' collate utf8_general_ci 
OR 
    a.`descricao` LIKE '%".$termo_pesquisa."%' collate utf8_general_ci
```

> ## 1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' não é válida para CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'

1 - Ambas as tabelas são [MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)

2 - inseri o collate para melhorar a busca de palavras chaves pois estava havendo ocultação de registros devido ao caixa alta dos caracteres.

Comment: Caro Eliseu, se criou as tabelas em utf8mb4 porque esta tentando **forçar** o `collate` no `LIKE`? Se a intenção for fazer comparações CASE-INSENTIVE e de acentos com não acentuados talvez deva experimentar `utf8mb4_general_ci`, ou melhor, confira se as tabelas já não são `utf8mb4_general_ci` ou `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, pq se as tabelas forem, usar collate com isto seria "redundância" (ou quase, depende do my.ini e do cliente). Eu não vou entrar em detalhes sobre o general e o unicode e suas diferenças, mas seria interessante postar a parte PHP [...]

Comment: [...] porque sua tentativa de usar collate pode ser para corrigir um problema que na verdade estaria no PHP

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado, a redundância foi eliminada e problema resolvido, está como utf8_general_ci sim, e forçando o collate estava dando erro, sem ele funcionou, não me lembro que situação fiz uso de collate e agora não faz sentido rs, obrg

Comment: Caro @EliseuB alguma de suas tabelas deve estar como utf8mb4, mesmo que o banco não, ou até mesmo pode ser uma configuração no `my.ini`, mas sem detalhes não posso ajudar. De qualquer forma tem que analisar seu php (se for php) ou conexão, esta bem ajustado para trabalhar as entradas de dados no SELECT (as variáveis), seria até mais interessante usar prepared_statment (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) ao invés de passar as variaveis diretamente , para evitar sqlinjection ou simplesmente evitar erro de sintaxe disparado por valores que contenham apostrofo

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado pelas dicas, as duas tabelas são uft8. é que a hospedagem seta o banco como utf8mb4 e não consigo alterar, logo mais irei migrar, e as variáveis são tratadas antes de serem passadas, e uso mysqli_real_escape_string() dentro, é que simplifiquei aí, tenho função que faz um belo tratamento de cada tipo de variável, obrigado por tudo.

Comment: quem cria o banco pode ser até o painel da hospedagem, mas as tabelas e o que `mysqli_connect()` é você, logo você é o responsável por tal ajuste e não a hospedagem.... Sobre o outro assunto, sim o `mysqli_real_escape_string` já ajuda, mas eventualmente você pode esquecer dele, se tiver bastante cuidado até vai :) ... Mas acho que um belo tratamento nas variaveis é o tipo de redundancia que só causa problemas no futuro, é tipo uma série de operações repetitivas e que volta e meia esquecemos, usar o que tem pronto, como prepared, já ajudaria e simplificaria, mas é apenas dicas :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento até mesmo dentro do phpmyadmin. Reconheceram o problema mas pediram que adaptasse o código.

Comment: Mas ai adaptar para funcionar na marra é gambiarra, que hoje pode funcionar, mas no futuro será problema :) .. ps: vou apagar quase todos comentários, menos o primeiro. Os demais aqui era só para lhe orientar